# Service in parent component run after child component

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a parent component that run a service on ngInit function. then I use data that received from service on child component. But it seems like the child component runs first and after that, parent component receives data from the service.
How can I receive data from the service first?

Parent Componet:

```
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

    public report: Report = new Report();

    constructor(private reportService: ReportService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        //get report detail data from API ............
        this.reportService.getReport('1')
      .subscribe(
        (data: any) => {
            this.report.serialNum_used_probe = data.serialNum_used_probe;
            this.report.created_datetime = data.created_datetime;
        }
      );
```

}

Comment: put the service in resolve of the route where this component is loaded?

Comment: I don't know how can I do that, Can you explain more?

Answer (score 1):

I have done these step:

1) create a ReportResolver class:

```
@Injectable()
export class ReportResolver implements Resolve<any>{

  constructor(private reportService: ReportService){}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, rstate: RouterStateSnapshot):   Observable<any>{
    return this.reportService.getReport(route.paramMap.get('pk'));
  }
}
```

2) Add this class to routes list:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'report/:pk', component: ReportComponent, resolve: {reportData: ReportResolver} }
];
```

3) Call http function in main component:

```
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

    public report: Report;
    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
                private reportService: ReportService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this.route.data.map(data => data.reportData).subscribe(
          (data: any) => {
             this.report = new Report();
             this.report.serialNum_used_probe = data.serialNum_used_probe;
             this.report.created_datetime = data.created_datetime;
       });

  }
}
```

and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you used something like *ngIf or @Input on child components to transfer the data from parent.

Consider not initializing your variables and create the instance after the API request:

```
export class ReportComponent implements OnInit {

    public report: Report;

    constructor(private reportService: ReportService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        //get report detail data from API ............
        this.reportService.getReport('1')
            .subscribe(
                (data: any) => {
                    this.report = new Report();
                    this.report.serialNum_used_probe = data.serialNum_used_probe;
                    this.report.created_datetime = data.created_datetime;
                }
            );
    }
}
```